# Is it possible to automate Outlook using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, outlook

I am trying to create a Python script that logs in to my Outlook account, opens the unread messages, and if it has attachments it downloads them.
However, after login, it seems that I am stuck and cannot do anything.
Are these activities out of the scope of Selenium?

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you run your python scripts?

You may find [REST API](https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted) helpful. But if you are talking about the desktop edition here is what MS states:

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) article.

If you deal only with Exchange profiles consider using EWS instead. See [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about outlook.com then yes, it's possible. I guess it's gonna require a lot of xpath though...